# Is a precompact countable union of relatively compact sets necessarily relatively compact?

Tags: banach-spaces, compactness, weak-topology

The topology considered is the weak topology on a Banach space.

Let each $A_i$ be relatively sequentially compact, and its countable union $\cup_i A_i$ be sequentially precompact (in the sense that for every sequence in it, a Cauchy subsequence exists).

*Qeustion*: does this imply that $\cup_i A_i$ is relatively compact?

*Remark*: Without the assumption that the union is sequentially precompact, this is not true, since we can choose singletons and make any sequence we want relatively compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the space is reflexive, then the union is relatively compact (since the dual of a Banach space is weak$^{\ast}$-ly sequentially complete, so a weak$^{\ast}$ Cauchy sequence is convergent).

If the space is not reflexive, the union can contain weak Cauchy sequences whose limit belongs to $X'' \setminus X$ (viewing the space $X$ as a subspace of its bidual $X''$). For a concrete example, let $X = c_0$ the space of sequences converging to $0$. Its dual can be canonically identified with $\ell^1$, and its bidual with $\ell^{\infty}$. Let $A_i = \{\sum_{k = 0}^i e_k\}$ for all $i$. As a finite set, each $A_i$ is compact, and

$$A := \bigcup_{i = 0}^{\infty} A_i$$

is (weakly) precompact as the underlying set of a sequence converging in $\sigma(\ell^{\infty}, \ell^1)$. But the limit - the constant sequence $\mathbb{1}$ - doesn't belong to $c_0$, so $A$ is not relatively compact in $\sigma(c_0,\ell^1)$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! 
Not any dual is weakly sequentially complete, right? (you say "since the dual of a Banach space is weakly sequentially complete", but do you mean to say that any reflexive space is weakly sequentially complete?)

Comment: That should be "weak$^{\ast}$-ly sequentially complete", will fix. Then, since we assume a Banach space, we have the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, which gives us the weak$^{\ast}$-limit. If the space is reflexive, it's the dual of its dual, and the weak and weak$^{\ast}$ topologies coincide.

Comment: In general, the dual of a locally convex space need not be weak$^{\ast}$-sequentially complete. I forgot what the criterion for that was, though.